# How to add an if-statement in a PHP and HTML mix?

Tags: php, html

I would like to add the `data-prefilltext` parameter only to the button if `$_GET['text'] != "undefined"`. How to achieve this?

HTML:

```
<button
id="sharebutton"
class="g-interactivepost"
data-prefilltext="<?php echo $_GET['text'];?>"
Send
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you wish `$_GET['text']` to be connected with string `"undefined"`

```
<button
  id="sharebutton"
  class="g-interactivepost"
  <?php if (isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text']) && $_GET['text'] !== 'undefined') { ?>
    data-prefilltext="<?php echo $_GET['text'];?>"
  <?php } ?>
>
  Send
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button>
 id="sharebutton"
 class="g-interactivepost"
 data-prefilltext="<?php if (isset($_GET['text'] && !empty($_GET['text']) { echo $_GET['text']; } ?>"
 Send
</button>
```

Is this what you're after?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

To keep the HTML cleaner, I would probably define a string outside of the actual HTML button element, as such:

```
<?php $prefilltext = isset($_GET['text']) ? 'data-prefilltext="' . $_GET['text'] . '"' : ''; ?>

<button id="sharebutton" class="g-interactivepost" <?php echo $prefilltext;?>>
Send
</button>
```

PS: I simply checked for the existence of `$_GET['text']`.  Of course you can change that to check for `empty` or any other comparison, such as `$_GET['text'] != 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following:

```
<button
id="sharebutton"
class="g-interactivepost"
<?php echo ($_GET['text'] != 'undefined')? "data-prefilltext=\"".$_GET['text']."\" ": "";?>
Send
</button>
```

Check out [Ternary Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) at php.net

Answer (score 0):

```
<button
id="sharebutton"
class="g-interactivepost"
data-prefilltext="<?php if(isset($_GET['text']) && !empty($_GET['text']) { if($_GET['text'] == "undefined") { echo $_GET['text']; } else { // if text is not equal to undefined }?>"
Send
</button>
```